# Uncheck Select All Checkbox when one checkbox is Unchecked C# in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a checkbox when you click on it it select all checkbox the problem here that when unchecked any check box checked didn't remove from select all I tried this code:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked == false) 
        checkBox9.Checked = false;
}
```

but when i checked any check box it remove all checkbox i want to unchecked select all only not all checkbox

Comment: If `checkBox9` is "select all" checkbox - your code should work, unless you have other eventhandlers which set it back to "checked" or you checking "wrong" checkbox, which would not be unusual when you use "deafult" names for controls

Answer (score 0):

1 - Add Timer On Your Project.
2 - Start Timer On "Form Load" event.
3 - Create timer tick event.

4- Write this code:

```
checkBox1.Checked != checkBox2.Checked
checkBox2.Checked != checkBox1.Checked
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not so clear, it probably solve your issue:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            if (CheckBox2.Checked)
            {
                CheckBox2.Checked = false;

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way of doing this is to iterate over all the checkboxes.  This will check all checkboxes on the form when you check 1.  And also unchceck all the checkboxes when you uncheck 1.

```
// Register the checked changed event and point all to the same event handler
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
checkBox2.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
checkBox3.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;

private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is CheckBox == false) return;

    var currentCheckBox = (CheckBox) sender;

    foreach (var checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(a => a != currentCheckBox))
    {
        checkBox.Checked = currentCheckBox.Checked;
    }
}
```